# Frequently repeated try/except in Python

Tags: python, exception

Firstly, I'm not sure if my approach is proper, so I'm open to a variety of suggestions.

If try/except statements are frequently repeated in code, are there any good ways to shorten them or avoid fully writing them out?

```
try:
    # Do similar thing
    os.remove('/my/file')
except OSError, e:
    # Same exception handing
    pass

try:
    # Do similar thing
    os.chmod('/other/file', 0700)
except OSError, e:
    #Same exception handling
    pass
```

For example, for one line actions you could define a exception handling wrapper and then pass a lambda function:

```
def may_exist(func):
    "Work with file which you are not sure if exists."""
    try:
        func()
    except OSError, e:
        # Same exception handling
        pass

may_exist(lambda: os.remove('/my/file'))
may_exist(lambda: os.chmod('/other/file', 0700))
```

Does this 'solution' just make things less clear? Should I just fully write out all the try/except statements?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: try-except as an Expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088009/python-try-except-as-an-expression)

Comment: Me and @kindall just answered this question very nicely yesterday.

Comment: @agf: That question seems partially related, thanks for linking. However Ned Batchelder's answer seems to have the advantage that there is no need to create a function out of the block of code for which exceptions need to be caught.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The best way to abstract exception handling is with a context manager:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
@contextmanager
def common_handling():
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        # whatever your common handling is
```

then:

```
with common_handling():
    os.remove('/my/file')

with common_handling():
    os.chmod('/other/file', 0700)
```

This has the advantage that you can put full statements, and more than one of them, in each common_handling block.

Keep in mind though, your need to use the same handling over and over again feels a lot like over-handling exceptions.  Are you sure you need to do this much?

Comment: I think this exactly what I was looking for, but I might be over-handling exceptions. In these cases I want to work with files only if they exist. I could check if they exist beforehand (os.path.filexists), but from what I understand, its better to try and catch exceptions in python?

Comment: In that case, it might make sense to catch the *first* exception, and then skip over the whole block of statements regarding that file if it didn't exist, but let all the other exceptions from the remaining operations propagate, since it's unlikely that the lack of exception in the first followed by an exception in the second is equivalent to file existence.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I'll look into what the best way to do that is.

Comment: @ned-batchelder Please update your answer to reflect the new [`ignored`](http://bugs.python.org/issue15806) context manager recently added. Found it while reading [Python is Awesome](https://speakerdeck.com/pyconslides/pycon-keynote-python-is-awesome) presentation.

Comment: @mmoya: this sounds like a perfect topic for a new answer!

Answer (score 4):

It would probably be cleaner to make `may_exist` a decorator:

```
from functools import wraps
def may_exist(func):
   @wraps(func):
   def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
       try:
           return func(*args, **kwds)
       except OSError:
           pass
   return wrapper
```

Then you can either do:

```
may_exist(os.remove)('/my/file')
may_exist(os.chmod)('/other/file', 0700)
```

for a one-off call, or:

```
remove_if_exists = may_exist(os.remove)
...
remove_if_exists('somefile')
```

if you use it a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I think your generic solution is ok, but I wouldn't use those lambdas at the bottom. I'd recommend passing the function and arguments like this

```
def may_exist(func, *args):
    "Work with file which you are not sure if exists."""
    try:
        func(args)
    except OSError, e:
        # Same exception handling
        pass

may_exist(os.remove, '/my/file')
may_exist(os.chmod, '/other/file', '0700')
```

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work:

```
def may_exist(func, *func_args):
    try:
        func(*func_args)
    except OSError as e:
        pass
```