# Python try except block inside lambda

Tags: python, lambda, try-except

Is it possible to use a try except block inside of a lambda function?  I need the lambda function to convert a certain variable into an integer, but not all of the values will be able to be converted into integers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108193/frequently-repeated-try-except-in-python

Comment: You don't _need_ a lambda function. Just use a named function in it's place

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Nope. A Python lambda can only be a single expression. Use a named function.

It is convenient to write a generic function for converting types:

```
def tryconvert(value, default, *types):
    for t in types:
        try:
            return t(value)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            continue
    return default
```

Then you can write your lambda:

```
lambda v: tryconvert(v, 0, int)
```

You could also write `tryconvert()` so it *returns* a function that takes the value to be converted; then you don't need the lambda:

```
def tryconvert(default, *types):
    def convert(value):
        for t in types:
            try:
                return t(value)
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                continue
        return default
    # set name of conversion function to something more useful
    namext = ("_%s_" % default) + "_".join(t.__name__ for t in types)
    if hasattr(convert, "__qualname__"): convert.__qualname__ += namext
    convert.__name__ += namext
    return convert
```

Now `tryconvert(0, int)` returns a function `convert_0_int` that takes a value and converts it to an integer, and returns `0` if this can't be done. You can use this function right away (not saving a copy):

```
mynumber = tryconert(0, int)(value)
```

Or save it to call it later:

```
intconvert = tryconvert(0, int)
# later...
mynumber = intconvert(value)
```

Answer (score 40):

In this specific instance, you can avoid using a `try` block like this:

```
lambda s: int(s) if s.isdigit() else 0
```

The [`isdigit()` string method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) returns true if *all* the characters of `s` are digits. (If you need to accept negative numbers, you will have to do some extra checking.)

Comment: had tried the same logic on re.search, worked as a charm. One-liner is beautiful.

Comment: This does not work with values such as `5.5`, which are valid inputs but do not return True for `.isdigit()`.

Comment: @Modelmat: The question specifically asks about *integers*.

Comment: It asks for converting a certain value to an integer. This does not specify whether this value has to be an integer to be valid. Additionally, this certain value does not even *have* to be a string. Notwithstanding, it is still useful to know.

Comment: Using `if` is a good point, but in "this specific instance", you'd need to write a lot more code to cover all the strings `int` accepts. You mentioned negatives, but there's also positives, whitespace (e.g. `int('9\t') == 9` but `'9\t'.isdigit() == False`), and underscores (e.g. `int('5_000') == 5000` but `'5_000'.isdigit() == False`). So it is actually easier to use try-except, unless OP is in fact only handling a subset. You could edit to clarify that easily, like "You can often use a conditional expression (`if`) instead. For example, if your inputs are all strings containing just digits:"

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted before thinking it over. I'd happily swap it for an upvote after an edit though :)

Answer (score 8):

## Yes, it is possible

I put together this little piece of code to demonstrate the possibility to catch exceptions and react to them inside a lambda. It's rather rudimentary and serves more or less as a proof of concept.

#### Example

```rb
>>> print_msg = lambda msg, **print_kwargs: \
...   begin(
...     print, msg, end='... ', **print_kwargs
...   ).\
...   rescue(
...     (TypeError, AttributeError),
...     lambda exc: print(f'just caught "{exc}"! how fun!')
...   ).\
...   ensure(print, 'ok done.')()

>>> print_msg('check')
check... ok done.

>>> print_msg('check', file=1)
just caught "'int' object has no attribute 'write'"! how fun!
ok done.

>>> print_msg('check', sep=1)
just caught "sep must be None or a string, not int"! how fun!
ok done.
```

#### A bit more practical example

```
modules = filter(None, (
  begin(importlib.import_module, modname).rescue(lambda exc: None)()
  for modname in module_names
))
```

### Code

```py
from typing import Iterable

class begin:

  def __init__(self, fun, *args, **kwargs):
    self.fun = fun
    self.args = args
    self.kwargs = kwargs

    self.exception_types_and_handlers = []
    self.finalize = None

  def rescue(self, exception_types, handler):
    if not isinstance(exception_types, Iterable):
      exception_types = (exception_types,)

    self.exception_types_and_handlers.append((exception_types, handler))
    return self

  def ensure(self, finalize, *finalize_args, **finalize_kwargs):
    if self.finalize is not None:
      raise Exception('ensure() called twice')

    self.finalize = finalize
    self.finalize_args = finalize_args
    self.finalize_kwargs = finalize_kwargs
    return self

  def __call__(self):
    try:
      return self.fun(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

    except BaseException as exc:
      handler = self.find_applicable_handler(exc)
      if handler is None:
        raise
      return handler(exc)

    finally:
      if self.finalize is not None:
        self.finalize()


  def find_applicable_handler(self, exc):
    applicable_handlers = (
      handler
      for exception_types, handler in self.exception_types_and_handlers
      if isinstance(exc, exception_types)
    )
    return next(applicable_handlers, None)
```

Answer (score 1):

While there is no general way for handling exceptions in a lambda expression, you can achieve it in a restricted way for at least one kind of exception; throwing a `StopIteration` from a part of an expression and catching it in another part is achievable; see:

```
from random import randrange

list((lambda:(yield from (randrange(0,2) or next(iter(())) for _ in (None,))))())
```

where `next(iter(()))` raises a `StopIteration` while `yield from` will catch it; the expression above randomly returns `[]` or `[1]` according to the inner random value (a `0` will raise the exception and a `1` will be normally evaluated).

You can read more about it ta http://baruchel.github.io/python/2018/06/20/python-exceptions-in-lambda/ .

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your need, another approach could be to keep the try:catch outside lambda fn

```
toint  = lambda x : int(x)
strval = ['3', '']

for s in strval:
    try:
        print 2 + toint(s)
    except ValueError:
        print 2
```

Output:

```
5
2
```