# Use context manager in lambda, how?

Tags: python, lambda, with-statement, contextmanager

How can I use a context manager in a lambda? Hacks accepted. Defer opinions about this being a bad usage of lambdas.

I know I can do this:

```
def f():
    with context():
        return "Foo"
```

But I would like to do something like this:

```
lambda: with context(): "Foo"
```

Comment: `f` is not a variable in your `lambda`.

Comment: Thanks, syntax mistake on my part. Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible workaround for getting lambdas working with a context manager is to make the context manager a `ContextDecorator`, then both `with` statements and `lambda` expressions will work because a lambda can use the decorator pattern instead.

## [Example](https://gist.github.com/carlthome/31ba4093a6f7029053de02d70fc48ef1)

```
from contextlib import ContextDecorator


def f(x):
     """Just prints the input, but this could be any arbitrary function."""
     print(x)


class mycontext(ContextDecorator):
    def __enter__(self):
        f('Starting')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        f('Finishing')
        return False

with mycontext():
    f('The bit in the middle')

mycontext()(lambda: f('The bit in the middle'))()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't replace the work `with` does with an expression, no. There are no hacks to get you there either, because there is no way to handle exceptions and finalisation within an expression.

That's because you can only use *one expression* in a lambda. `with` is a *statement*, not an expression. You'd have to replace that with exception handling (`try..except..finally`) and calls to the [`__enter__` and `__exit__` methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) (storing the `__exit__` method *first*). However, exception handling can *only* be done with statements, because an exception ends the current expression immediately. See [Python Try Catch Block inside lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451531/python-try-catch-block-inside-lambda).

Your *only option* is to stick to using a proper function instead.

Comment: What about ContextDecorator?

Comment: Like [this](https://gist.github.com/carlthome/31ba4093a6f7029053de02d70fc48ef1) for example. Is there a problem with that in case of raised exceptions or something?

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that one. `ContextDecorator` is not part of the lambda expression. It produces a new function object that contains the `with` statement, then calls the original function, and does all the exception handling. That's something different. And the context manager explicitly needs to support that use.

Comment: I'd say making a context manager extend `ContextDecorator` instead of calling `contextmanager` is pretty trivial refactoring for getting lambdas to work with context managers though. In other words, there is an option. Are you aware of any downsides to this? Thanks for answering!

Comment: @CarlThomé: yes, you can't apply `ContextDecorator` to existing context manager objects, and you can't access whatever `__enter__` returns (what is assigned to `<name>` in `with <contextmanager> as <name>`). At that point you can either write a dedicated decorator function (and pass in the `as` result), or just write a function and use `with`.