# Python Define IFERROR function

Tags: python, exception

I'm trying to define my own IFERROR function in python like in Excel.  (Yes, I know I can write try/except.  I'm just trying to create an inline shorthand for a try/except pattern I often use.)  The current use case is trying to get several attributes of some remote tables.  The module used to connect to them gives a variety of errors and if that happens, I simply want to record that an error was hit when attempting to get that attribute.

What I've tried:
A search revealed a number of threads, the most helpful of which were:

[Frequently repeated try/except in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108193/frequently-repeated-try-except-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Python: try-except as an Expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088009/python-try-except-as-an-expression)

After reading these threads, I tried writing the following:

```
>>> def iferror(success, failure, *exceptions):
...     try:
...         return success
...     except exceptions or Exception:
...         return failure
...
>>> iferror(1/0,0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

I also tried using a context manager (new to me):

```
>>> from contextlib import contextmanager as cm
>>> @cm
... def iferror(failure, *exceptions):
...     try:
...         yield
...     except exceptions or Exception:
...         return failure
...
>>> with iferror(0,ZeroDivisionError) as x:
...     x=1/0
...
>>> print(x)
None
```

Is there a way to define a function which will perform a predefined try/except pattern like IFERROR?

Comment: `return success()` and `iferror(lambda: 1/0, 0)`?

Comment: I still get a division by zero error using that.  If it works for you, can you post the full code that is working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with `iferror(1/0,0)` is that function arguments are evaluated before the function is entered (this is the case in most programming languages, the one big exception being Haskell). No matter what `iferror` does, `1/0` runs first and throws an error.

We must somehow delay the evaluation of `1/0` so it happens inside the function, in the context of a `try` block. One way is to use a string (`iferror('1/0', 1)`) that `iferror` can then [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval). But `eval` should be avoided where possible, and there is a more light-weight alternative: Function bodies are not evaluated until the function is called, so we can just wrap our expression in a function and pass that:

```
def iferror(success, failure, *exceptions):
    try:
        return success()
    except exceptions or Exception:
        return failure

def my_expr():
    return 1/0

print(iferror(my_expr, 42))
```

```
42
```

The crucial part here is that we don't call `my_expr` directly. We pass it as a function into `iferror`, which then invokes `success()`, which ends up executing `return 1/0`.

The only problem is that we had to pull the function argument (`1/0`) out of the normal flow of code and into a separate function definition, which we had to give a name (even thought it's only used once).

These shortcomings can be avoided by using `lambda`, which lets us define single-expression functions inline:

```
def iferror(success, failure, *exceptions):
    try:
        return success()
        #             ^^
    except exceptions or Exception:
        return failure

print(iferror(lambda: 1/0, 42))
#             ^^^^^^^
```

```
42
```

[[Live demo](https://tio.run/##ZY5LDsMgEEP3nMJLqJD6XWXfg1AyqEgpoGGQmtPTTxJ1Ua9sWU92meWe07n3kQJiIObMujbvqVaL4OLUmCx29PRUJOZUzaDwlvC8mI@YpHHCymnzLRYEPxKZcd3SH7xuKVU4JtHbl8k9bqMbcNwfLC4nY3p/AQ)]

Compared to your original attempt, only two changes were necessary: Wrap the expression in a `lambda:`, which delays evaluation, and use `()` in `try: return success()` to call the lambda, which triggers evaluation of the function body.

Comment: This is a general technique that also works in e.g. [Perl](https://tio.run/##TY1LDoIwEIb3PcUsSIAEEYlsaOIpuEBtBmyClUxbtTGcvRZB4@z@13wT0tiE4AzCvSnrqqw4W8RDkFZ6MKvC54SkrqitGCE1atDCOkKTrnFHvm07pT1nzLgzqB6JbpQlxkmJxhSQ9EKNcZHDi0E8wrjXYMlvxnLf@u6U5R9zBimsvPxXtj9rzNkcgcL/gAs8iww47CuYCzjWOQ/hDQ) or [JavaScript](https://tio.run/##TY3NCgIxDITvfYocG1h/8bbou5RsqpXSSNoKIvvsXZUqzmlgvpm5urvLpOFWVkkmbs3XRCVIguBZVdTmSsQ5D@BdiFUZ4WngpaKP7t5SLlUTdNji@ElmIFfoAvbX@mP7XifNbAxJyhJ5HeVsv/cW4XiC3WY7wGGPOLa2AA) (but the latter doesn't think `1/0` is an error and just returns `Infinity`).

Answer (score 2):

Well I found a way but I'm not quite sure, if it's that what you are looking for. 
First of all the error occurs if you call the function, as a result your function doesn't start at all! So I gave the first parameter of the function a string. 
So the function gets your "test" and "controls" it with `eval()`. Here is my Code:

```
def iferror(success: str, failure, *exceptions):
    try:
        # Test
        return eval(success)

    except exceptions or Exception:
        return failure    

iferror("1/0", "Hi there!")
```

I hope I could hope you.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, using eval.  Obviously, not everything will work with eval, but I think that can be my back-up plan.  If no one can come up with a different way, I'll pick this as the answer.