# Improve upon the try-catch python method

Tags: python-2.7

I am basically trying to improve upon [Python: try-except as an Expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088009/python-try-except-as-an-expression) with a couple of features

- Ability to pass in extra args and kwargs to the "try-except" question. This is because I have a success function which takes in a few parameters
- Failure function if callable should be called with the exception argument so it gets a chance to handle it.

Here is a sample code with a test however I am not able to get the last line to work

```
def method2(exc_class = None):
    if exc_class:
        raise exc_class()

def method1():
    return "Hello world"

def try_except(function, failure, exceptions = [], args = [], kwargs = {}):
    """
    Run the given function with args and kwargs. If it throws one of the
    exceptions in the list then either return failure or call failure function
    """
    try:
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    except exceptions or Exception as e:
        return failure(e) if callable(failure) else failure

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Prints hello world
    print try_except(method1, "Failure") 
    #Prints Failure great!!
    print try_except(method2, "Failure", kwargs = {"exc_class" : ValueError})
    # I expect below line to print "Failure" properly but it throws a ValueError
    print try_except(method2, "Failure", kwargs = {"exc_class" : ValueError}, exceptions=[ValueError])
```

My question here is the `except exceptions or Exception as e:` line does not substitute the list of exceptions properly. I cannot do *exceptions as shown in the original question because  I want to take in extra parameters for the function.

I am okay to change the try_except to some extent though.

Note: I have considered doing a catch all `except Exception as e` and then checking if the exception class in in the list and if it is not then rethrow it. However that won't work because when I rethrow the original stack trace is lost and I do not want to do that.

Comment: In the reference question `exceptions` was a tuple. The fact that it was passed in with a `*` doesn't make any difference to that. So try using a tuple instead of a list: `try_except(..., exceptions = (), ...)`

Comment: That is correct indeed. I thought I tested it with both tuple and list but apparently not. Thanks for the clarification @PeterWestlake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When catching several exception types with one `except` clause, you can't use just any iterable object; you must specifically use a `tuple`. You can still allow `try_except` to take any iterable as an argument by creating a tuple in the `except` clause itself.

```
try:
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
except tuple(exceptions or (Exception,)) as e:
    return failure(e) if callable(failure) else failure
```

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-try_stmt):

> For an except clause with an expression, that expression is evaluated, and the clause matches the exception if the resulting object is “compatible” with the exception. An object is compatible with an exception if it is the class or a base class of the exception object, or a tuple containing an item compatible with the exception.