# Python: try-except Expression always get the default value when I try to apply it on http request

Tags: python, http, exception, xmlhttprequest

I use some google API as fellow:

```
def get_address(lat, lng):
    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?{}".\
      format(urllib.parse.urlencode(args))
    ...
    try:
       r = requests.get(url)
       ...
       return r
    except OSError as e:
       raise NetException(e.message, 400)
```

while I try use the try-exception handle the excption if the network errors.
[the try-exception Expression is from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088009/python-try-except-as-an-expression)

```
def try_except(success, failure, *exceptions):
    try:
        return success()
    except exceptions or Exception:
        return failure() if callable(failure) else failure
```

But when I try to use these exception I always get the failure reults of http, even if I get successful result if I simply run the success function.

```
>>> re=get_address(-33.865, 151.2094)
>>> re
'Sydney'
>>> r=try_except(get_address(-33.865, 151.2094),"")
>>> r
''
```

How to make sure the successful result would get correct string reuslt, while the onlly failture of http request get the failure result?

Comment: This is why you should always catch the specific exception you expect. You're catching all `Exception`s, hiding the very useful exception message that would have told you exactly what was going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the function as `success` argument. Currently in

```
r=try_except(get_address(-33.865, 151.2094),"")
```

you are passing result value of `get_address(-33.865, 151.2094)` which is `'Sydney'`. The actual error is raised on trying to call `success()` which translates to `'Sydney'()` - something like `str object is not callable`

Proper call would be

```
r=try_except(lambda: get_address(-33.865, 151.2094), '')
```