# Pythonic way of assigning value to a variable if statement does not raise exception

Tags: python, exception

I would like to assign value to a variable if a certain statement does not raise exceptions. If exceptions occur, `None` should be assigned. What is the pythonic way to achieve this?

Here is a concrete example of what I'm trying to do:

```
try:
    bar = foo(data['buzz']) # data is a dict
except KeyError:
    bar = None
```

Points to note:

- `KeyError` may result from `buzz` not existing in `data`
- `foo` can still throw an exception (of any kind, depends on it's implementation) even if `buzz` exists in `data`

Comment: This is good and readable. Also might want to note that `bar` is set to `None` if a `KeyError` occurs inside function also.

Comment: Your question is very vague. However, maybe something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088009/python-try-except-as-an-expression is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your approach is readable, you might want to consider the following.

**Caveat?**

`bar` will be set to `None` if a `KeyError` occurs inside function also:

```
data = {'buzz': 1}

def foo(x):
    abc_value = data['abc'] # this raises a `KeyError` inside function `foo`.

try:
    bar = foo(data['buzz']) # data is a dict
except KeyError:
    bar = None

print(bar)
# None
```

**Solution:**

Better way you can avoid this is to avoid using `try-except` as it's scope is nested as well:

```
if "buzz" in data:
    bar = foo(data["buzz"])
else:
    bar = None
```

Even more *pythonically* in one line:

```
bar = foo(data["buzz"]) if "buzz" in data else None
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, another way to avoid the problem raised by Austin, with other `KeyError`s in `foo` (not caused by `"buzz"` being missing from `data`) triggering the `except` clause, would be to use the `else` clause:

```
try:
    val = data["buzz"]
except KeyError:
    bar = None
else:
    bar = foo(val)
```

This `else` clause would be executed in the event that the statements within `try` did not raise `KeyError`.

Of course, in this case you would be better explicitly testing whether the `"buzz"` key exists in the dictionary, as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to do this in your example is:

```
if "buzz" in data:
    bar = foo(data["buzz"])
else:
    bar = None
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're specifically asking about a dictionary, you can use `myDic.get(key)` instead of `myDict(key)`, why? because `get()` provides a `fallback` value, what's a fallback ? in case `key` is not in `myDict`, use the fallback value, in your case:

```
bar = foo(data.get('buzz', None) # if buzz is in data, return data["buzz"] else None
```

Comment: This is not the same and would result in passing `None` to `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

```
bar = [f if 'buzz' in data else None for f in data][0]
```

The `[0]` part isn't as pythonic as I would like...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `foo` doesn't raise a KeyError:

```
bar = foo(data['buzz']) if 'buzz' in data else None
```

However, I think your approach is cleaner and more correct, based on the pythonic pattern of "ask for forgiveness rather than permission" described here: https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/readability/asking_for_permission_instead_of_forgiveness_when_working_with_files.html